# Forcing a site to SSL (via IIS) causes WebResource.axd loading issues

Tags: asp.net, iis, ssl

We have forced the LIVE site to use SSL (for authentication reasons) and now the site won't get past the Login page.
The Login page displays fine, but after entering Username/Password and hitting Login, the page reloads.

> Looking at the Developer Tools in Chrome reveals a **404 error** loading
>   https://myapplication.com/login.aspx/WebResource.axd

Research on internet suggests a web.config setting - but I can't find what setting to use.

The site works absolutely fine when not in SSL mode - and has been working for a while until forcing IIS to run site over SSL at all times.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not programming. Try serverfault

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have bindings on 443 for all the URI's possible.  For example, you have myapplication.com.  You probably have a binding on 80 to that URI, but what about 443?  What about www.myapplication.com on 80 and 443?  IIS will only respond if told to.  It will not infer URLs from the application that it should serve up.  You have to specifically allow them on all ports.